# DQL joining related entities

Tags: symfony, dql

Hi have some entities relateds and need to define a dql query to obtain an entity.

**MAIN ENTITY**

```
class proyectosSubsecciones
{
    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="app\SubseccionesBundle\Entity\Subsecciones")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_subseccion", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $subseccion;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="app\ProyectosBundle\Entity\Proyectos")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_proyecto", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $proyecto;
    ....
```

**RELATED ENTITY**

```
class subsecciones
{
    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="app\SeccionesBundle\Entity\Secciones")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_seccion", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=false)
     */
    private $seccion;
    ...
```

I need to obtain the distinct entities of type "app\SeccionesBundle\Entity\Secciones" from each "app\ProyectosBundle\Entity\Proyectos"

I´m trying a query like:

```
$consulta=$em->createQuery('
            SELECT DISTINCT sc
            FROM ProyectosSubseccionesBundle:ProyectosSubsecciones p
            JOIN p.subseccion s WITH s.id=p.subseccion
            JOIN s.seccion sc WITH sc.id=s.seccion
            WHERE p.proyecto= :id
        ');
$consulta->setParameter('id', $id_proyecto); 
$subsecciones=$consulta->getResult();
```

I get an error that says:

"Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias"

But I only need the data from sc.Any idea??

Comment: Do share the definitions for Proyectos & Secciones

Comment: If you need data from "sc" - write "SELECT DISTINCT sc". Why is it "SELECT DISTINCT ss"? What is "ss"?

Answer (score 2):

Use query builder in `ProyectosSubseccionesRepository`:

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
     ->join('p.subseccion', 's', Join::WITH, 's = p.subseccion')
     ->join('s.seccion', 'sc', Join::WITH, 'sc = s.seccion')
     ->where('p.proyecto = :id')
     ->setParameter('id', $id)
     ->getQuery()
     ->execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

For your problem i assume you have defined [`bidirectional`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional) relationship among your entities.

like

```
Entity                      RelationType    ReferenceEntity         Reference
==========================================================================================
ProyectosSubsecciones       ManyToOne       Subsecciones            $subseccion
ProyectosSubsecciones       ManyToOne       Proyectos               $proyecto
Proyectos                   OneToMany       ProyectosSubsecciones   $proyectosSubsecciones
Subsecciones                OneToMany       ProyectosSubsecciones   $proyectosSubsecciones
Subsecciones                ManyToOne       Secciones               $seccion
Secciones                   OneToMany       Subsecciones            $subsecciones
```

Considering above [`bidirectional`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional) definitions you can write your DQL as

```
SELECT DISTINCT s
FROM Secciones s
JOIN s.subsecciones ss
JOIN ss.proyectosSubsecciones pss
JOIN pss.proyecto
WHERE p.id = :id
```

The above query will select `Secciones` entity and join with `Subsecciones` entity using property `$subsecciones` defined in `Secciones` entity.

Then query will join  `Subsecciones` with `ProyectosSubsecciones` using property `$proyectosSubsecciones` defined in `Subsecciones` entity.

Finally it will  `ProyectosSubsecciones` with `Proyectos` entity using `$proyecto` property defined in `ProyectosSubsecciones` entity and lastly it will apply a filter according your `WHERE` clause.

> Note there is no need to use `WITH` clause to join your entities because, In DQL, joining part will be covered by properties which you define as `OneToMany/ManyToOne or ManyToMany` `WITH` is used for if there is no relation mapping defined between entities or if you want to add another filter on joining criteria like `ON(a.id = b.some_id AND/WITH some = some)`